# Lambda decay into neutron and photon

Tags: nuclear-physics, conservation-laws

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_baryon), a $\Lambda_0$ particle typically decays into a nucleon and a pion (via the weak interaction).
However, I checked all the conservation laws that I know and the reaction $\Lambda_0 \rightarrow n+\gamma$ seems to be allowed as well (via the weak interaction).

Why does this reaction not occur in reality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [the PDG list of decays](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/tables/rpp2023-tab-baryons-Lambda.pdf) for the $\Lambda^0$. The probability of a decay to a neutron and a photon (that is, the [branching ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_fraction) for this process) has been measured at $(8.3\pm0.7)\times10^{-4}$. This is much less common because unlike the two common decay modes, it requires a weak vertex *and* an electromagnetic vertex. So you shouldn't phrase it as "via weak interaction". Rather, you should phrase it as "via the weak interaction and the electromagnetic reaction." The electromagnetic part further suppresses the decay by a factor of $\alpha$.

Here's a "Feynman diagram" describing the process. I put Feynman diagram in quotes because I feel Feynman diagrams involving Hadrons often have ambiguous and misleading meaning... they neglect QCD and thus can only be used for order of magnitude estimates. I'm not really a particle physicist so I don't know what the standard way to draw these is, but here you go.

[image]

Note this is one of MANY possible diagrams. The E+M vertex can go in a lot of different places.

Comment: I would also be interested in how you draw this Feynman diagram. How would this look like?

Comment: @Riemann I put a diagram. Originally I didn't put one for the reasons I described in the new paragraph. Also I don't know how to do mathjax diagrams so it's ugly. But you asked so there you go.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused about how to draw it and now I see that you have to swap the up quark from the second to the third line.